# How can I format documents that are not saved in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, plaintext

If i  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (or use the command from the palette) on a ***Untitled*** tab on *vscode* the following command appear:

> There is no formatter for 'plaintext' files installed.

Is there any way to specify a different format for the unsaved file to enable the formatter of choice?

This need usually arise when I usually copy/paste some json/xml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**
Now the new tab shows directly a selection mode that says:

> Select a language to get started. Start typing to dismiss, or don't show this again.

So you just need to press <kbd>Select a language</kbd>

[image: visual studio code selection mode]

**UPDATE 1**
In the bottom right corner is available the `Select Language Mode` functionality that now let you select a formatting option, the default one is `Plain Text`. The same functionality can be used with <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> or by selecting `Change Language Mode` from the command palette.

[image: Select Language Mode in Visual Studio Code]

**OLD ANSWER**
I found two solutions to this specific problem, even if they seems more a workaround than a proper solution:

1. Using a specific extension to format particular code (json or xml)
2. Trick VSCode into thinking default unsaved files are json

### 1 Extensions that format as specific code

Install specific extension that add language specific commands:

- [XML Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DotJoshJohnson.xml)
  default keybinding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- [JSON Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eriklynd.json-tools)
  default keybinding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

PRO

- no default settings are changed
- specific format can be used on any selection in any file
- it's the same solution that notepad++ implement

CONS

- additional extensions to download may look overkill only to format something
- more keybindings and additional non standard behaviours

### 2 VSCode default unsaved files trick

Add a configuration to settings.json that specify json as the type of document for untitled files:

```
"files.associations": {
    "Untitled-*" : "json"
}
```

PRO

- default ***Format document*** is used
- no additional download is required

CONS

- only one format can be specified
- locale-dependant (in languages other than English it should not work)

Answer (score 14):

In the latest VS Code (v1.47):

The detected file type is printed on the lower bar of the window, and by default it'll likely say `Plain Text` for new, unsaved, files.

[image: Screenshot of visual studio code lower-right menu-bar]

Click on `Plain Text`, that'll bring up a box where you can select other formats VS Code knows about. Select the one you want or start typing what you want in the search, such as `JSON`, and that'll convert the detected file-type over.
Now you can use the standard `Format Document` command from the command palette, so long as VS Code has a formatter for that file-type.